# Keras Look Ahead not training with RAdam

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I'm attempting to use look ahead with RAdam as the inner optimizer. I've tried Look Ahead with Adam as the inner optimizer and seperately I've used RAdam as the optimizer with good results. However, when I try to use Look Ahead with RAdam accuracy actually gets worse during training.

I've verified that training goes well when these optimizers are run separately. I've also tried with and without warmup using RAdam.

```
from keras_lookahead import Lookahead
from keras_radam import RAdam

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 20
Ranger=Lookahead(RAdam(total_steps=10000, warmup_proportion=0.1, min_lr=1e-5))

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Ranger,
              metrics=['accuracy'])



history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The model trains but accuracy starts poor (.0851) and gets worse (.0836). Any ideas why

Comment: Forgot to mention you need to import some libraries first:                            from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam

Comment: I noticed that after I reinstalled RAdam, RAdam is no longer working. It had been working before